# How to connect ACS712 Current Sensor to raspberrypi2?

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I have a voltage sensor like this [ACS712 Current Sensor](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/Capteur-de-tension-voltage-sensor-25V-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-ESP-/271662316634) and I didn't understand how to connect it to raspberrypi2.
All the tutorials that I found on the net concern A rduino.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What interface does this sensor use? SPI, I2C? is it analog or digital? Linking to a foreign language ebay page is not the most helpful.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=61122

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS497US497&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=acs712+raspberry+pi&*

Comment: @SteveRobillard I'm searching through the net and I didn't find a clear tutorial.

Comment: No useful tutorial :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACS current sensors give voltage output with respect to the current following through them. Raspberry pi doesn't have any ADC pins so you will need an ADC to go between raspberry pi and the ACS sensors or you can get an ACS sensors which come with an ADC so that you can directly plug it into the raspberry pi. something like this [ACS sensor with ADC](https://shop.controleverything.com/collections/energy-monitoring/products/1-channel-dc-current-monitor-for-i2c) once you have the ADC hooked up you can read the ADC values and convert them into the real current values. For better results, you will need to take multiple readings and average them.

Comment: What about using MCP3008 or ADS1115 16-BIT with raspberrypi2?

Comment: @xhunter both the MCP300x and ADS1xxx ADCs work well with the Pi, and there are a ton of code examples in many languages around the 'net.