# Energy consumption measurement using ACS current sensor

Tags: networking, power, measuring

I want to build an energy consumption meter using my Raspberry Pi. I have done some research, and determined that the ACS712 current sensor could be interfaced with my RPi for this purpose. I do not understand electrical jargon very well, and so I am asking this first question here to determine feasibility and a general approach.

Comment: Which sensor, ACS712?

Comment: if it's the ACS712 current sensor, then, yes, it is possible to measure energy consumption using such a sensor, as that is what the sensor was created for

Comment: using *google* I found https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=173831 and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63052/how-to-connect-acs712-current-sensor-to-raspberrypi2 and https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/12/adc-pi-with-acs712 - these are the first three search results - there are a few more

Answer (score 3):

Your question might lead some to believe that you haven't done much research before posting. Only you know what you did before posting, but I'll suggest that you read the [guidelines here for asking a "good question"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); this will give you some insight into how others might see your question.

That said, I'll try to answer some of your questions, as I understand them:

1. "Is it possible to measure my energy consumption using ACS current sensor..."?

> Yes, but know that "energy consumption" is not directly measured by taking a current reading. Energy consumption is the product of **power** and **time** (i.e. **E = P*T**), and is measured in terms of **watt-hours** or (sometimes) [**joules**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule).
>
> [**Power**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) is the product of **current** and **voltage** (i.e. **P=V*I**), and measured in [**watts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt). [**Current**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) is measured in [**amperes** (or **amps**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere), and [**voltage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage) is measured in [**volts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt).
>
> One way to help keep this straight is to look at your electric utility bill. Note that you are (likely) billed on your usage in "kilowatt-hours", and electric power producers often quote their rates as $/£/€ per kilowatt-hour. So you're buying ***energy*** from your supplier - not power, or current because those are instantaneous measures.

2. "... then how to do it?"

> Based on the above, and in general, you will **measure** voltage, current and time, and then you will multiply them together to get energy:
>
> **E = V * I * T**
>   And if your units are volts, amps and hours, then your result (E) will be in **watt-hours**.
>
> With all of that out of the way, as a practical matter, here's **how** you might proceed:
>
> - time: you can measure time in software in any number of ways; for example in `bash`: `timestamp=$(date +%T)`, or in `Python` use the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module. You'll need elapsed time of course, so measure time when you commence your electrical readings, and then again when you finish a measurement.
> - voltage: you can most likely get the voltage value from a specification. Also, if your power source is a constant voltage source (dc or rms), you could also take a measurement, and use that value with little loss in accuracy.
> - current: At long last, this is where you will use your ACS current sensor. You should probably be using the [ACS723](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS723.aspx) chip instead of the [ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx), since the `712 has been declared as "Not for new design", but they operate on the same principle - they are ["Hall Effect Sensors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor). There are plenty of resources detailing the hardware connection that can be consulted for the price of a Google search, and so I'll leave that for you. Most fortunately, there is a [Python library for the ACS712](https://github.com/abelectronicsuk/ABElectronics_Python3_Libraries/blob/master/ADCPi/demo-acs712-30.py) that should make your software interface much easier.

I hope this helps get you started. We'll leave it up to you to do a bit of research, and fill in some details. Once you've tried something, and if it doesn't work, please post those specific questions here iaw the guidelines in [The Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour)